# page_load in system.web.ui.page not called

Tags: asp.net, pageload

I have been looking around yet I can't find any that fits in my problem.

I am doing this in c# asp.net visual studio 2005, i have a master page and removed the Page_Load event from there since i wanted the Page_Load in the pages other than the master to fire. So in one of the pages other than the masterpage:

- ***in page1.aspx:***

  ```
  public partial class page1 : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           (this.Master as IMasterPage).SetSelected("gtm");
      }
  }
  ```
- ***in masterpage.cs:***

  ```
  public partial class Master : System.Web.UI.MasterPage, IMasterPage
  {
      #region ImasterPage Members
      public void SetSelected(string name)
      {
          switch (name)
          {
              case "gtm": 
                  this.gtm.CssClass = "gtm_sel"; 
                  break;
              default: break;
          }
      }
      #endregion
  }
  ```

the codes shown are for the horizontal, single-level main menu somewhere on top of page and i wanted the menu selected to highlight after the page reloads but the page_load on the page1.aspx does not seem to be called!

This is the part of the menu in the masterpage:

```
<div id="menu" class=''>
    <ul>                   
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="com" CssClass="gtm" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/page1.aspx"><span>Courses</span></asp:HyperLink></li> 
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="tbm" CssClass="tbm" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/page2.aspx"><span>Team Building</span></asp:HyperLink></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="ptm" CssClass="ptm" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/page3.aspx"><span>Personal Training</span></asp:HyperLink></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="atm" CssClass="atm" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/page4.aspx"><span>Adventure Tours</span></asp:HyperLink></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="gtm" CssClass="stm" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/groupTraining.aspx"><span>Group Training</span></asp:HyperLink></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

all css styles for hover and selected (eg: gtm_sel) are defined and working properly in the sense that when i bypass the page load even from page1.aspx onto the page_load event of the master page calling it from there like: this.SetSelected('gtm'); it works like a charm

haywired.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `AutoEventWireup="true"` in the Page directive...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```